# How to define 'if and only if' in linear programming with 3 integer variables

Tags: constraints, linear-programming

So have this 3 integer variables (A, B and C) and I have this constraint:

> A can only be used if both B and C are used.

So, if the variable would be used would be equal to 1.

Any idea how to formulate this constraints in linear programming? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the variables are binary use `A <= (B + C) / 2`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe standard form for that type of constraint is just 2 simple constraints:

```
A <= B
A <= C
```